# Proof of $q-1\mid mn$ implies $ \frac{q-1}{\gcd(q-1,n)}\mid m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble proving the statement in the title;
my first idea was to rewrite $q-1 = a \cdot \gcd(q-1,n)$ with $\gcd(a, n) = 1$, but I can't seem to figure out a way to finish this proof.

Edit.
I solved this problem with a generalized version of Euclid's lemma: ("If a product $ab$ is divisible by $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(n,a)=1$, then $b$ is divisible by $n$.")

With this lemma its quite easy to see the proof by writing $n = b \cdot \gcd(q-1,n)$. Using this, you can rewrite $q-1|mn$ as $a|mb$ with \gcd(a,b) = 1. Using the lemma, the implication follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$q-1=\gcd(q-1,mn)\mid\gcd((q-1)m,mn)=m \gcd(q-1,n)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$q-1|mn \iff \frac{mn}{q-1} \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\frac{q-1}{(q-1,n)}|m \iff \frac{m(q-1,n)}{q-1}\in \mathbb{Z}$$
Note that only factors of $n$ common to $q-1$ that gets cancelled, so if we replaced $n$ with $(q-1,n)$, it should not be a problem.

If this is too informal, here's another one.

The condition gives $mn=(q-1)a$ for some integer $a$. Using the fact that $ab=(a,b)[a,b]$,
$$\frac{q-1}{(q-1,n)}|m \iff \frac{m(q-1,n)}{q-1}\in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\iff \frac{mn}{[q-1,n]} \in \mathbb{Z} \iff \frac{a(q-1)}{[q-1,\frac{(q-1)a}{m}]}\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: $q=7$, $n=4$, $x=2$, $y=2$, $\gcd(y,q-1)\ne1$.

Comment: OK, but why does the last equivalence hold?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because $a|a(q-1)$ and $\frac{(q-1)a}{m} |a(q-1)$ (*least* common multiple)

Comment: That's why the last inclusion holds. But why does that inclusion imply the one before it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I made a typo.